# Error: 'ID1039: The certificate's private key could not be accessed

Tags: c#, azure, ssl

I am implementing ADFS authentication in azure but I face the following problem:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: ID1024: The configuration property value is not valid.

Property name: `serviceCertificate`

> Error: 'ID1039: The certificate's private key could not be accessed.
>   Ensure the access control list (ACL) on the certificate's private key
>   grants access to the application pool user.

Thumbprint: 'df113454dsf1321(value here I changed the value)''

when I right click on the certificate and then click all task then it not show me the option for Manage Private Keys and gave access to IIS user.
How I fix the problem.
web.config file contents:

```
<serviceCertificate>
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="dfdsfdfdf(here I changed the value)" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</serviceCertificate>
```

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine?

Comment: Manage Private Keys is only available on Local Computer store, not Current User?

Answer (score 13):

I was getting same issue. The fix is, to allow the AppPool user (NETWORK SERVICE) to read the certificate private key).

- Open the MMC snap-in by running mmc.exe.
- Select File -> Add/remove snap-in. Select Certificates and click “Add”.
- Select “Computer Account”. Click Finish. Click Next.
- Drill down to Personal -> Certificates.
- Right-click your certificate and select All Tasks -> Manage private keys.
- Add NETWORK SERVICE and give it “read” privileges.

Thanks,
Shivesh

Comment: In my case IIS_IUSRS was the correct account. NETWORK SERVICE did not work.

Comment: I tried with NETWORK SERVICE account but it didn't work. IIS_IUSRS worked for me.

Comment: A more appropriate value is 'IIS AppPool\<your app pool>', this is more secure since it allows only the targeted application pool.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that even though you have the certificate, the private key is not installed in the right place. I got the same error, but adding the correct user (IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool) was not sufficient. I also had import the .pfx:

On Windows 7
-Open MMC
-Add Certificates snap-in to manage Local Computer
-Right click Personal store, All Tasks->Import
-Select the .pfx file (NOT the default .crt/.cer)
-Enter password, complete the wizard

This got my local site working when nothing else I Googled worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Application Pool setting for the particular application.
In Application pool advanced setting : Identity should be NetworkService.